# Написание нескольких подряд приставок, которые поодиночке пишутся слитно

Tags: орфография, приставка, слитно-дефис

Я не могу вспомнить правило, но вроде бы было какое-то про то, что если в слове несколько приставок, то все они пишутся через дефис, даже если в обычных случаях (когда приставка одна) они пишутся слитно.

К примеру, «анти-» пишется слитно и «супер-» — тоже. Но если эти приставки используются в одном слове (к примеру, что-то вроде *супер-анти-бактерия*), то все они — через дефис. Я уверен, что читал когда-то такое правило, но не могу вспомнить и найти его.

Надеюсь, я понятно сформулировал мысль...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно же, приставки [анти](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8) и [супер](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80) пишутся со словами слитно.
Возможно, вы имели в виду такое [правило](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80).

> § 152. Недопустимо слитное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть слова содержит дефис. Слитное написание должно заменяться дефисным, в результате чего возникают написания с двумя дефисами. Например, следует писать: *полу-конференц-зал, полу-социал-демократы, **ультра**-ура-патриот, радио-мюзик-холл, теле-пресс-конференция, теле-ток-шоу, **анти**-социал-демократический, лже-тред-юнионистский, **псевдо**-историко-революционный.*

Даже если первая часть сложных слов пишется слитно (анти, архи, супер, псевдо, транс, пост, гипер...), то перед дефисно пишущимся словом или прописной буквой **ставится дефис**:
анти-Маяковский, сверх-Мефистофель, пред-Моцарт, пан-Америка;
супер-мини-компьютер, супер-мини-ЭВМ, супер-реалити-шоу, контр-топ-спин,  пост-соц-арт.

P. S. Наречие [поодиночке](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5) пишется слитно.